# Where should I read up on sorting posts in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, datetime, sorting, rating

Just an open ended question - I'm using rails 3.0.9. I want to experiment with sorting systems. I'll want to start with a simple upvote/downvote system, and then try out more complex iterations.

However, I would want not to sort simply on upvotes/downvotes but provide a controllable skew for time (so that really interesting posts eventually give way to new ones).

Anyone have any suggestions on where to read about these sorting algorithms either generally or in rails(3)-specific sources?

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Not exactly what you're looking for, but relevant and interesting: http://blog.reddit.com/2011/07/nerd-talk-tale-of-life-of-link-on.html.

Comment: very very relevant, thanks! and nice username.. (hello to you too!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try [meta-where meta-search](http://metautonomo.us/projects/metawhere/) in this project sorting was talked about using meta-search gem. i hope this helps